# How to find port number

Tags: python-3.x

i am trying to find which port is available for pc but i am unable would you tell me the process how to find port

```
import socket

client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host = socket.gethostname()
ip = socket.gethostbyname(host)

def portFinder(port):
    try:
        client_socket.connect((ip, port))
        return True
    except:
        return False

for x in range(1, 200000):
    if portFinder(x):
        print("port {} is open for host {}".format(ip, x))
    else:
        print("No")
```

Comment: to see if the port is open, you could use `client_socket.connect_ex((ip, port))` - but this is still rather slow... and make sure to call `client_socket.close()` at the end.

Comment: them maybe you should print the open ports only. Oh BTW, swap the parameters of the print format

Comment: IINW you're trying to find out what ports are open on the same host using this script? If using python is not a must you can try using `lsof` - which will be much faster: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-check-if-port-is-in-use-command/

Comment: Note: the code "works", but on my virtual natted machine `gethostbyname(gethostname())` gives me `127.0.1.1`, which is different from `127.0.0.1` (localhost), producing different results

Comment: what should i do